# Get all depending IProject references for a given IProject

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an IProject that is also an IJavaProject.  I need to find all other projects in the workspace that refer to this IProject.

One simple and inefficient way of calculating this is to trawl through all projects in the workspace and keep track of references to the current project.  Something like this:

```
IProject currentProject = ...;

IProject[] allProjects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
List<IProject> interestingProjects = ...;
for (IProject project : allProjects) {
  if (refersToCurrentProject(project)) {
    interestingProjects.add(project);
  }
}
doSomething(interestingProjects);
```

Note- I haven't compiled this code and I wrote it from memory, so it may not work exactly, I am only trying to give an idea of what I want to do.

Another possibility is to calculate the dependencies only once and then update the dependencies through an IResourceChangedListener.  But, this is messy too and I need to write my own (error-prone) logic for that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that there is a context menu option to close unrelated projects when you right click a particular project. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  It looks like the CloseUnrelatedProjectsAction is using IProject.getReferencedProjects().  This is not exactly what I want since all projects in the workspace must be visited.

Comment: As I was looking through this, I noticed that there is a method IProject.getReferencingProjects().  The JavaDoc describes exactly the behavior I am looking for.  However, the implementation is a bit naive and searches through all projects in the workspace.  I am beginning to think there is no simple answer for this.

Comment: In the end, this is the way I am implementing.  Thanks for the original suggestion.  I'm not particularly happy with the results, but I don't think I can do much better without managing the state myself.